# How to store chat messages in Redis using Erlang client?

Tags: erlang, redis, ejabberd

I am working in android chat application using ejabberd as a server and Redis as a database for storing chat messages.I want to store conversation's message,From ,To and some fields in  Redis using erlang client.I studied about redis. List data type will be best to store chat's messages.But I couldn't find any example to implement using List.Is there any example to store chat messages in list. Or tell me if there any other alternate to store chat messages in Redis?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can store JSON into list, But if you have a functionality when a user can delete a message then you will have to find the exact position in list and then delete it. If I would have been at your place, I will store it into ZSET like:-

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD chat 1 "{from:me, msg: hello}"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD chat 2 "{from:you, msg: hello}"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD chat 3 "{from:me, msg: how are you}"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD chat 4 "{from:you, msg: good, how about you}"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD chat 5 "{from:you, msg: are you there}"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD chat 6 "{from:me, msg: yes i am}"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE chat 0 -1
1) "{from:me, msg: hello}"
2) "{from:you, msg: hello}"
3) "{from:me, msg: how are you}"
4) "{from:you, msg: good, how about you}"
5) "{from:you, msg: are you there}"
6) "{from:me, msg: yes i am}"
```

Instead of 1, 2, 3 (Score) you can use timestamp so using ZRANGE you can fetch the conversation easily.

Comment: I used your answer. But a small drawback is , If I use same member as previous one present in ZSET, previous one will be replaced by new member. refer: http://redis.io/commands/ZADD

Comment: I understand what you mean so in that case you can add timestamp with the message to every msg will be consider different...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I will use it.

Answer (score 1):

At http://gitweb.tideland.biz you can find ERRC, my Tideland Erlang/OTP Redis Client (ERRC). Beside the sources there are also unit tests showing the usage.

In your concrete task I would identify each message with a UUID (you'll find it in my ERAS library, also there) and use hashes for the messages:

```
HMSET msg::(UUID) timestamp ... from "foo" to "bar" text "Hello, World" ...
```

This is a kind of event sourcing. And then, for better navigation, individual lists for all messages or by sender, receiver etc.:

```
LPUSH msgs::all (UUID) LPUSH msgs::from::foo (UUID)
LPUSH msgs::to::bar (UUID)
```

Retrievals can be done with `LRANGE key start stop`. Here you'll get the UUIDs of the messages which you then can read with `HGETALL (UUID)`.